# How to Synchronize SQL Server Database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, synchronization, replication, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm planning to make a system that will utilize a **central corporate database** and several **local in-house database.**

Connection between the central database and local databases would depend on the local's availability (The central database is always online). So I'm thinking of synchronizing them by "pushing" updates from the local database to the central database using a website user interface and vice versa.

The central database is expected to have decent and stable internet connection. So it just sit there waiting for updates from local databases. Also local systems should have the capability to download updates from some tables that are only updated from the central database. The local system should only contain local information and general settings set by the central system. Local systems have no capability to see other local information in other branches(This capability is only for the central system).

So basically, information that are pushed to the central database are only modified in the local system and the data downloaded from the central database are only updated from the central database. So the local system can live and operate on its own, and the only true purpose of the central database is to create an overview of all the updates.

I've already checked Microsoft Sync Framework and it looks promising. I just can't find any tutorial that could demonstrate it completely. I'm hoping for a solution that can be implemented using a website interface. Just a nice  button in my local system's page.

If anyone would be able to point me to good source or starting point, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Sync Framework is an SDK, so you will have to code using the framework  for the synchronization part. You might want to have a look at SQL Merge Replication: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151763.aspx

Comment: I haven't tried it but you could use the commercial Zumero sync solution http://zumero.com/features/ I think it basically syncs SQL server to SQLite, so all you client apps read and write to SQLite and Zumero takes care of syncing it with SQL Server. They say it's for mobile apps in most of the marketing, but I think it supports clients on desktop such as Windows: http://zumero.com/dev-center/zss/#zssclientsdk You are basically paying for someone else to handle all the hard syncing for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have just finished my Microsoft Sync Framework research. In fact, MSDN provided all the solutions that you need. In my opinion, you don't have to pay for any commercial sync solution as you could get it done by yourself. Basically, you have to understand the overall structure of Microsoft Sync Framework: [Concept of Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb821992.aspx). Besides that, there are two type of sync module available which is 2-Tier and N-Tier Synchronization. Please study 2-Tier and N-Tier if you doesn't know about it. However, here is a good starting point for you to begin the N-Tier Synchronization [N-Tier Sync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902831.aspx). Meanwhile, you can set your synchronization direction to match with various kind of situation [Sync Direction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726039.aspx). In addition, data conflict could be occur in certain situation which should be handled [Data Conflict Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb725997.aspx).

Comment: just to clarify, there's no such thing as 2-tier or n-tier modules in Sync Framework. the 2-tier/n-tier is how you code the synchronization and not specifically from Sync Framework.